# A holomorphic function in the open unit disk satisfying certain properties

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-functions, taylor-series, divergent-series

Does there exist a function which is holomorphic in $|z|<1,$ continuous in $|z|\leq1$ and such that the series $\sum |a_n|$ is divergent, where $a_n$'s coefficients in the Taylor series expansion of $f?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are lots of classical examples by Hardy and Littlewood like say $f(z)=\sum _{n \ge 1}e^{in \log n}\frac{z^n}{n^{3/4}}$.

Using the second derivative test for exponential sums with $f(u)=(u\log u+u\theta)/(2\pi)$, so $f''(u) \sim 1/M$ when $u \sim M$, the exponential sum $\sum_{n=M}^{2M}e^{in\log n}e^{in\theta} =O(\sqrt M)$ uniformly in $\theta$ and an easy dyadic argument shows that $\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{in\log n}e^{in\theta}=O(\sqrt N)$ also uniformly in $\theta$, so it follows that $f$ converges uniformly on the unit circle and obviously satisfies $\sum |a_n|=\infty$

Comment: Can you please provide some references where such examples are given?

Comment: Zygmund classic book on Trigonometric Series 3rd edition Chapter 5 has this and many others with references to the original papers. See https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/trigonometric-series/14770B6E25C9C2A3447D8F56C622201F

Comment: I have few doubts. (1) why you are taking $f(u)=(u\log u+ u\theta)/2\pi?$  (2) how $\sum |a_n|=\infty?$

Comment: the exponential sums are generally taken as $\sum_{n \sim M}e(f(n))$ where $e(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$ so here since we have $e^{in\log n +in\theta}$ the corresponding $f(u)=u\log u+\theta u$ requires the $2\pi$ normalization, but that is just a convention; since $|a_n|=n^{3/4}$ clearly $\sum |a_n|=\infty$

Comment: Isn't $a_n=e^{in\log n}/n^{3/4}$ here?

Comment: Correct but $|e^{in \log n}|=1$

Comment: Ah! Yes, you're right. At last, can you give some more references wherein original reference are given. I didn't find orginal references in Zygmund's book

Comment: This particular (class of) series appears in the 1916 paper of Hardy and Littlewood Some Problems of diophantine approximation: A Remarkable Trigonometric Series https://www.jstor.org/stable/83478  however the discussion in Zygmund and the proof of convergence there is simpler - the proof of divergence (and more) when $3/4$ is replaced by $1/2$ though needs the original paper